# Can you help me fix the error in my code

Tags: php

I got the following error when I try to display the post array element. How can I fix it?

> Notice: Undefined index: ans in C:
>
> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:

HTML CODE

```
<input type = "radio" name = "ans[<?php echo $id; ?>]"
    value="A"/>A. <?php echo $A; ?><br />
<input type = "radio" name = "ans[<?php echo $id; ?>]"
    value="B"/>B. <?php echo $B; ?><br />
<input type = "radio" name = "ans[<?php echo $id; ?>]"
    value="C"/>C. <?php echo $C; ?><br />
<input type = "radio" name = "ans[<?php echo $id; ?>]"
    value="D"/>D. <?php echo $D; ?><br /><br />
```

PHP CODE

```
<?php

    $db= new mysqli("localhost","root","","test");

    if ($db->connect_error) {
       echo "error connect database".$db-connect_error;
    } else{
         mysql_select_db("test") or die ("Unable to select database: " .mysql_error());
    }

    foreach($_POST['ans'] as $option_num => $option_val) {
        echo $option_num." ".$option_val."<br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: The mysql_* extension that you've used was ***REMOVED*** from version 7 of PHP. You should now be using either the mysqli_* extension (note the "i" in there) or PDO and should also use prepared statements

Comment: Does your form use GET or POST? If you're using GET that's why `$_POST` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `$_POST['ans']` because the values of your name attribute do not come as just `'ans'`. Instead, they are printed as `'ans' + the id you echoed`. For example, let's say your id in the option A of your answers is 1, we will then have `'ans[1]'` thus `$_POST['ans[1]']`.

So, in general, you have to take care of that part of the string that makes your name attribute complete, which comes from `<?php echo $id; ?>`, meaning if for example $id is 1, then `name = "ans[<?php echo $id; ?>]"` will be the same as `name = "ans[1]"` and you will request it as `$_POST['ans[1]']`.

Hope this helps you out. You're welcome.

Comment: Actually PHP automatically converts POST requests with square brackets in them to an array. `<input name = "ans[1]">` will be used in PHP as `$_POST['ans']['1']`.